# How do I get more music (vinyl records)?

Tags: pit-people

I see that I can have other music options but I haven't found other discs in the wild. How do I get the rest?

[image: change music]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The records have **[a one percent drop chance](http://steamcommunity.com/app/291860/discussions/0/142261352656215476/#c142261352656364950) after each battle**. Some are still missing from the game, perhaps all but the below purple one. The developer is still working on music rights, so he recommends against grinding for them. I found one after one of the three minor missions:

[image: Record at end of level]

[image: Purple record]